# Convert from .NET MVC 2 to Django

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, legacy-database

Our .NET MVC 2 app is over-engineered. That data models are solid, but everything else is a mess.

Is there  away to "point" Django at our MS SQL Database, and have it generate the basic scaffolding and Admin interfaces from our existing DB structure?

Answer (score 1):

["Integrating Django with a legacy database"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/)

Answer (score 0):

Django works with SQL server via ado_mssql. It uses the adodbapi adapter, see link below.

http://adodbapi.sourceforge.net/